# How to conditional add expression ANY() inside WHERE() in IQueryable EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have a scenario where i need to add conditions inside ANY() inside WHERE() condition

```
IQueriable<Lead> c = DBContext.Lead;

if(Retailer)
{
  if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(country))
  {
    c = c.Where(x=> x.Retailer.ShopAddress.Any(s=>s.country == country);
  }
  if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(street))
  {
    c = c.Where(x=> x.Retailer.ShopAddress.Any(s=>s.street== street);
  }
  if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pin))
  {
    c = c.Where(x=> x.Retailer.ShopAddress.Any(s=>s.pin== pin);
  }
}else
{
   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(country))
  {
    c = c.Where(x=> x.Customer.HomeAddress.Any(s=>s.country == country);
  }
  if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(street))
  {
    c = c.Where(x=> x.Customer.HomeAddress.Any(s=>s.street== street);
  }
  if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pin))
  {
    c = c.Where(x=> x.Customer.HomeAddress.Any(s=>s.pin== pin);
  } 
}
```

- i need to add the condition inside ANY() as a like method so if street and pin is given then it needs to be on the same record.
- here the result will be like OR condition.
- how to use a method in the place of ANY() to return it as a single ANY with conditionally added conditions?
- I need it only on lambda.

Comment: Can you please explain the problem statement properly? Not able to understand what exactly you want here

Comment: Is `c = c.Where(x=> x.Customer.HomeAddress.Any(s=> (s.country == country || string.IsNullOrEmpty(country)) &&  s.street== street || string.IsNullOrEmpty(street)) &&  s.pin == pin || string.IsNullOrEmpty(pin));` an option?

Comment: Thanks @ThomasAyoub it will work but the conditions are too big in real scenario this will make an hell of an statement to read, but thanks.

Comment: I rephrased a little @RavirajPalvankar hope you will understand.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate approach could be to alter the way you have organised the Retailer and Customer. Assuming both a customer / retailer is a lead have an inheritance relation with Lead.

```
Customer : Lead
```

as well as

```
Retailer : Lead
```

You can now have common property for Address rather than HomeAddress and ShopAddress. 
Now You have halved the structure above. 
You can next have three predicates one each for country street and pin and use only if the input string is notempty. You can next or the three predicates based on existence.

```
Predicate<Address> countryPred = new Predicate<Address>(a => a.country == country);
Predicate<Address> streetPred = new Predicate<Address>(a => a.street == street);
Predicate<Address> pinPred = new Predicate<Address>(a => a.pin== pin);

Predicate<Address> finalPred;
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(country))
{
   if(finalPred == null)
      finalPred = countryPred;
   else
      finalPred = c => finalPred (c) || countryPred (c);
}
..
..
..

c = c.Where(x=> x.Lead.Address.Any(s=> finalPred));
```

Comment: You can use `Predicate` instead of `Func<Address, bool>`

Comment: solution is awesome, but we are using ENTITY in EF inheritance is not possible like this.Is there any other way of using this? @Neeraj

Comment: I get error like Operator || cannot be applied to operands of type Predicate<Address> and Predicate<Address> @Neeraj

Comment: We need to pass the value like finalPred = c =>  finalPred(c) || countryPred(c); @Neeraj

Comment: Have you tried one of tpt, tph, tpc https://entityframework.net/tpt. Refer to this link should be helpful.